# How to avoid a looping redirection from .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've set a .htaccess with a set of rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|javascript|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^Canvas/(.*)/(.*)$ /canvas.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The above rule get redirected and throwing 500 internal server error.

When I comment the last line, everything that follows the rule /canvas/something/something is working fine but things are going wrong when un-comment the last line.

I tried adding condition like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/canvas.php.*
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !^/canvas.php.*
```

but it didn't resolved the problem.

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try adding an environment variable to mark the fact you've redirected and trap for this using a `RewriteCond`. For example (untested):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|javascript|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^Canvas/(.*)/(.*)$ /canvas.php?a=$1&b=$2 [E=REWRITEDONE:1,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REWRITEDONE} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[L]` does not do what you think it does: It only stops "this round" and restarts the rewriting execution with the new URL. You might want to try `[END]`.

See [End vs Last flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end).

Alternatively, you cant try using the skip flag `[S=number_of_rules_to_skip]`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are happening here. First, `/canvas.php` is getting rewritten to `/index.php/canvas.php`. Then `/index.php` itself is getting rewritten to `/index.php/index.php/canvas.php`, and then that keeps looping. Your second rule has no conditions to prevent it from blindly rewriting everything that matches `^(.*)$` (which is everything). Note that `RewriteCond`'s *only* affect the immediately following `RewriteRule`, so the one that routes to `/index.php` won't have any conditions on it. A few conditions that you can add to prevent the looping:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|canvas\.php|images|stylesheets|javascript|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Rewrites everything that *isn't* `index.php`, `canvas.php`, images, stylesheets, scripts, and the robots.txt file. Or:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Rewrites everything that *isn't* pointing to an existing file or directory. This also excludes direct access to stuff like scripts and styles and the robots.txt, along with any other static content.

Another possibility is to prevent looping entirely, by adding this to the top of your rules (right below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This means if there's already an internal rewrite, stop rewriting completely by passing through the URI (the `-` target). The rewrite engine loops until the URI going in stops changing, the passthrough essentially does that. If you are using apache 2.4, you can also use the `END` rewrite flag to stop rewriting.